# Changing the label of Change Password Form

Tags: views, 8

How to change the form label from `Password` to `New Password` and `Confirm password` to `New Confirm password` on `THEME_form_user_form_alter`(without changing any `twig` files)? I had tried `kint($form['account']['pass'])` to see any possible way, no clue...

**Current Change Password Form**

Current password

|||||||||||||||||

Password **(to New Password)**

|||||||||||||||||

Confirm password **(to New Confirm password)**

|||||||||||||||||

```php
function THEME_form_user_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  kint($form['account']);
}
```

There are no `#title` element on `pass` field.

[image]

Comment: looks to me that `current_pass` must be coming from a custom or contrib module, as mine doesn't have that.

Comment: @NoSssweat, how about 'pass', I would like to change the label to "New Password"

Comment: These `#title`s are defined in `/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element/PasswordConfirm.php`. It looks complicated to change, you might have to just do it via javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to create a new module and use [hook_element_info_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_element_info_alter/8.6.x)
to alter title input like this:

```
function my_module_element_info_alter(array &$types) {
  if (isset($types['password_confirm'])) {
    $types['password_confirm']['#process'][] = '_mymodule_change_title';
  }
}
```

and process function

```
function _mymodule_change_title(&$element) {
  $element['pass1']['#title'] = t('New title 1');
  $element['pass2']['#title'] = t('New title 2');
  return $element;
}
```

and as a result

[image]